# Disable in renders not working?

Tags: rendering

New to Blender here.
I want to disable a certain object from rendering for a certain period of time, so I assigned keyframes from frame 1 to 30 for it to not render. Yet it doesn't seem to be working? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Image for reference. Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, it seems that it's only being disabled on the final rendered model rather than on render preview. I suppose it works for me

Comment: "Disable render" works only in "Render" yes. Though feel free to also animate the viewport visibility if it helps, but be careful there are many things you can't do on an object while hidden in the viewport.